# Getting error in UDP connection

Tags: c#

I am having a problem when I try to close the application by clicking the 'X' which is on the right side of the form I am getting an error which says

> The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exist or an application request

And I am getting at this line of code:

```
newsocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar,ref tmp);
```

Here is the example of my code :

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int m;
        Socket newsocket;    
        EndPoint tmp;
        IPEndPoint sen = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001);
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        public Form1()
        { 
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
            IPEndPoint endpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 1235);
            newsocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram,ProtocolType.Udp);
            newsocket.Bind(endpoint);
            tmp = (EndPoint)sen;
            newsocket.BeginReceiveFrom(data, 0, 40, SocketFlags.None,ref tmp, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), tmp);
            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.threadtask));
            thread.Start();
        }

        protected void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
        {
            newsocket.EndReceiveFrom(ar,ref tmp);
            send();
            newsocket.BeginReceiveFrom(data, 0, 40, SocketFlags.None, ref tmp, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), tmp);
        }

        private void send()
        {
            newsocket.BeginSendTo(buffer, 0, 7, SocketFlags.None, sen, newAsyncCallback(SendCallback), sen);
        }

        protected void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            newsocket.EndSendTo(ar);
        }

        private void threadtask()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                cMicroLCCore.getDAC(m).Value = data[m];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.threadtask));
thread.Start();
```

receiver thread is running in background, I don;t see any code which would handle form unload and graceful closing of your receiver thread. That is what you need to do - stop your thread (you will need to store thread reference in your class variable) when you are closing the form.

Comment: @ Germann:Thanks for your answer but i am actully new in programming could you please tell me how can i do that by some example .

Comment: Define `Thread thread;` as a class variable.  
Define `form_unload()` handler and run  
`thread.Stop();` inside your unload handler.

Comment: What is it that you tried, what do you mean by "nothing is happening"? Edit (or add) your code to your post.

Comment: Hello i have tried with **form_closing()** event i wrote **thread.abort();** inside my closing event but then **it is showing me the error which is object reference not set to an instance of an object**.                                     private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {  thread.abort(); }

Comment: @user1465977 "you will need to store thread reference in your class variable" - did you do that? Instead of method-local variable `Thread thread = ...;` you should define `Thread thread` as class instance variable, keep the assignment were it is, later you will be able to use `thread` anywhere in your class.

Comment: Thanks Germann I am really grateful of you ...you helped me..now my code running with out any error i just set **thread.IsBackground = true**   then its woring fine...thanks once a again for ur help..